# Rename files in a folder using Python, using name map from Excel

Tags: python

There are many CSV files in a folder which I want to renamed. There is an excel sheet which contains name of files to be renamed to folder.

The files in folder are named as

```
TestData_30April.csv

TestData_20April.csv

TestData_18April.csv etc
```

while the excel sheet contains the name as

```
0.25-TestData_30April.

0.98-TestData_20April

0.33-TestData_20April
```

My Aim is to rename

"TestData_30April.csv" to "0.25-TestData_30April.csv"

similarly

```
"TestData_20April.csv" to "0.98-TestData_20April" etc.
```

my Problem Defination is similar to this one Here is the link "Rename files with Python, using name map from Excel"

Kindly and Please Help i am new to python.

Here is the Code and its not working

```
import os

import xlrd

**#Excel Sheet containing name of files to be renamed in that folder**

path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test_Data\\Test_Summary.xlsx"

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path) 

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

**#In excel sheet column X or col_values(23) contains the file name to be renamed**

print(sheet.col_values(23))  

new_names = sheet.col_values(23)

for new_name in sheet.col_values(23):



if '-' in new_name:

    old_name = new_name.split("-")[1]

    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, old_name)):

        os.rename(os.path.join(dir, old_name), os.path.join(dir, new_name))
```

Kindly help i am new to python

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error but the file names in the folder are not renamed

Comment: is filename in the csv is always like this `*.**-[].csv` format ?

Comment: The file names in the folder are TestData_30April.csv ,TestData_20April.csv , TestData_18April.csv in this format.  While in excel sheet file names are 0.25-TestData_30April, 0.98-TestData_20April ,0.33-TestData_20April are in this format.

Comment: prashant rana : I want to rename files in the folder but the new file name to be renamed is available in excel sheet(Column-X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_of_filename_in_folder = [] # name of the files in the folder
list_of_filename_in_excel = [] #name of the files in excel

path_to_folder = ''  # base path of folder  

for name in list_of_filename_in_excel:
    excel_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder, name,'.csv')
    dir_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder,name.split('-')[1],'.csv' )
    if os.path.exists(dir_file_name):
      print('changing file name {} to {}'.format(name.split('-')[1],name))
      os.rename(dir_file_name, excel_file_name)
    else:
      print('no file {} with name found in project location'.format(name.split('-')[1]+'.csv')
```

Comment: Prashanth: above is not renaming files in the folder after i run the script

Comment: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list' is the erroe

Comment: have you added the data in the the list ? don't know what data your are passing, code is correct

Comment: Can you please clarify what Data i need to add to that list?? I Mean i added list_of_filename_in_folder = [dir path] and list_of_filename_in_excel = [excel path] resp. Is it correct??

Comment: `list_of_filename_in_folder =['TestData_30April.csv' ,'TestData_20April.csv' , 'TestData_18April.csv'] ` and `list_of_filename_in_excel = [ '0.25-TestData_30April', '0.98-TestData_20April' ,'0.33-TestData_20April']`    `path_to_folder = C:\user\<username>\project\``

Comment: running this on jupyter notebook or on python konsole

Comment: spyder (Python 3.6)

Comment: no file TestData_30April.csv with name  found in project location. I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

The filenames in you excel sheet do not contain the extension .csv, therefore the `old_name` is the filename without extension, while `os.path.isfile` checks the full filename and only returns true when filename and extension are all match.

Append the extension to your excel sheet and try again, it should work.

```
0.25-TestData_30April.csv
0.98-TestData_20April.csv
0.33-TestData_20April.csv
```

Comment: But file names in folder and names in excel sheet are random

Comment: just include the filename extension `.csv` in the random filenames in your excel sheet.

Comment: dir_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder,name.split('-')[1],'.csv' )